# Как объединить двух провайдеров, увеличив скорость интернета?

Tags: windows, маршрутизация, router

Есть два интернет провайдера.
Как можно при скачивании, например, торрентов, использовать сразу двух провайдеров?

Либо как-то прописать айпи-адреса. Если один, то подключиться к одному провайдеру, а если другой - то к другому. Ну либо как-то по другому.
Можно ли прописать в роутере? Либо ставить две сетевых карты? (Конечно, лучше в роутере, чтоб с каждым компом не заморачиваться).

Спасибо.

Comment: Вам это только для торрентов нужно?

Comment: @koks_rs в большей степени для торрентов, но хотелось бы и что б и другие проги тоже по такой же системе работали

Comment: Смотрите в сторону bonding: объединение нескольких физических адаптеров в один.

Comment: Ну так и получалось что либо в консоли писать маршруты ручками имея 2 шлюза в сети либо же подключить два провайдера в микротике и прописывать маршруты в ip/routes. в первом варианте удобно что если под себя настраиваешь, то можно указать сети, через нужный шлюз туда будет ходить трафик нужного приложения.

Answer (score 5):

Распределение нагрузки с лёгкостью можно реализовать на базе Mikrotik
Вся суть процесса сводится к настройке 2х каналов интернета,настройки NAT, удалить шлюз по умолчанию, и назначить в качестве шлюзов эти 2 канала в зависимости от пропускной способности.

192.168.1.249 - 1шлюз
192.168.222.1 - 2шлюз

вариант для балансировки 50/50

```
 ip route add dst-address=0.0.0.0/0 gateway=192.168.1.249,192.168.222.1
```

Предположим, что у первого провайдера скорость доступа в два раза выше чем у второго, тогда 2/3 исходящих запросов надо направить на первого, а оставшиеся 1/3 на второго.

```
 ip route add dst-address=0.0.0.0/0
gateway=192.168.1.249,192.168.1.249,192.168.222.1
```

[Полное описание процесса настройки](http://www.routerbox.ru/news/balansirovka-kanalov-/)

[Более развёрнуто о способах балансировки нагрузки](http://mum.mikrotik.com/presentations/UA12/lukin.pdf)

ПС. Однако всякого рода Http, Https, ftp и тому подобный трафик нужно будет маркировать и направлять ручками (или возможно используя скрипты)) на определённый канал дабы исключить вариант смены IP при обновлении страниц к примеру

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы вы могли одновременно работать через двух провайдеров, вам надо, чтобы ваш белый ip маршрутизировался обоими провайдерами. Это возможно только в случае [PI-адресов](http://www.ripn.net/nic/IP-reg/FAQ.html), но сейчас IPv4 такие адреса вы не получите. Только IPv6.

Варианты с маршрутизацией на железке проблемны тем, что для  сервера в инете у вас будет то ip от одного провайдера, то ip от другого. И большинство серверов будет полагать, что это разные клиенты и требовать заново авторизации, установления сессии и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Сомневаюсь, что рядовые роутеры спомобны на такое.
Подключите 2 роутера в одну сеть. На втором роутере отключите раздачу DHCP. На клиентских ПК укажите либо 2 шлюза с одинаковыми приоритетами, либо одной половине клиентов укажите один шлюз, а второй половине - другой.

Answer (score 0):

В "продвинутых" роутерах возможно разделить трафик между двумя провайдерами.

При этом минимальный квант разделения - это сессия. Не знаю, могут ли такое роутеры, тем более в авторежиме (а совсем хорошо - с учётом загрузки канала). Вон товарищ уверен в Микротике.

Малой кровью можно обойтись, если на одном из WAN-интерфейсов не указывать шлюза по умолчанию, а в настройке маршрутизации прописАть через него маршрут(ы) в половину Инета (адрес/маска, делить на глазок). Тогда всё, что попадает под указанные подсети, пойдёт через второго прова, а остальное через того, чей остался дефолтный шлюз. Желательно при этом трафик на узлы одного провайдера не пускать через шлюз другого.

А вот вариант, когда трафик сессии идёт то через одного, то через другого провайдера (или через обоих одновременно) невозможен - потому как для этого нужна соотв. договорённость и настройка синхронизации между ними, а зачем ИМ это надо?